# Sending object to a function, getting wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a function where I am sending JSON. Then I used `console.log` to view it. My code is

```
function json($data) {
  console.log($data);
} 

json({
  "first_name": "First Name",
  "last_name": "Last Name",
  "phone": "Phone",
  "orgname": "Organisation Name",
  "email": "Email",
  "1": "Sign-up Date"
});
```

In the `console.log($data);` I receive the output like  this:

```
{
  1: "Sign-up Date", 
  first_name: "First Name", 
  last_name: "Last Name", 
  phone: "Phone", 
  orgname: "Organisation Name", 
  email: "Email"
}
```

However I need it like this

```
{
  first_name: "First Name", 
  last_name: "Last Name", 
  phone: "Phone", 
  orgname: "Organisation Name", 
  email: "Email", 
  1: "Sign-up Date"
}
```

The problem is that instead of `console.log` I'm actually using this code:

```
$.each($data, function(index, value) {
    $(".custom_fields_with_names").append('<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>');
});
```

and am getting the options in the wrong order (with "1" coming first).

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: (Rory's fixed it for you.)

Comment: Is problem consider ordering?

Comment: You cannot reorder the properties of an object. You also cannot rely on them being in the same order when worked with. If you need to have data in a specific order, use an array instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had to so I could understand what was actually being asked

Comment: Although JavaScript objects *do* have an order (as of ES2015; and your example `console.log` with the `1` property first is using that order), the order is **not important** in virtually any situation. What makes you think you need the object in a particular order?

Comment: U can use Object.keys to get *array* of keys, order them in desired way and then operate with it. Iterate by ordered key but take values from object.

Comment: Your objects that are returned are the same and the order doesn't really matter here since you access the value by a given key. However, maybe it's worth looking at `Map` introduced in ECMAScript 2015

Comment: Nobody's going to mention how `json` is a terrible function name?

Comment: *"I made a function where I am sending a json"* No, you're sending an object. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Technically he could send the function anything, since it just logs the argument passed to it.

Comment: `const sort=o=>Object.keys(o).sort().reduce((p,c)=>(p[c]=o[c],p),{})
console.log(sort(obj))` Do you mean this?

Comment: @3142maple and how this should give possibility to keep desired object's keys order?

Comment: Hey Actually after the console.log I am using ` $.each($json, function(index, value) {
        $(".custom_fields_with_names").append('<option value="'+index+'">'+value+'</option>');
    });`
to append the values in select box

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder for guiding me

Comment: @Vitalli just sort the keys of the object

Comment: If you're using it to create an option list like you're describing, you definitely want a Map ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018907/javascript-json-sending-to-a-function/50019240#comment87054468_50018907):

> Hey Actually after the console.log I am using `$.each($json, function(index, value) { $(".custom_fields_with_names").append('<option value="'+index+'">'+value+'</option>'); });` to append the values in select box

That indicates you want to maintain order. If so, don't use an object. While JavaScript objects *do* have an order (now, as of ES2015), using it is almost never the right thing to do, and as you've noticed, the order they have is not the order you want (specifically: property names that qualify as *integer indexes* are listed first, in numeric order, and then remaining properties are listed in creation order [if we only consider "own" properties]).

Instead, provide the data to your function in an ordered structure such as an array:

```
json([
  {name: "first_name", value: "First Name"},
  {name: "last_name", value: "Last Name"},
  {name: "phone", value: "Phone"},
  {name: "orgname", value: "Organisation Name"},
  {name: "email", value: "Email"},
  {name: "1", value: "Sign-up Date"}
]);
```

and then

```
$.each($data, function(index, entry) {
    $(".custom_fields_with_names").append('<option value="' + entry.name + '">' + entry.value + '</option>');
});
```

---

I've used `$.each` because you did, but of course you could use `$data.forEach(function(entry) {...` instead. I've also only used ES5-level features as there wasn't any indication in your question that you're using ES2015+ features.

Comment: Thanks, for explaining every reason behind it. Much Appreciated